# Relational product in Alloy

Tags: logic, alloy

I have the following Signatures

```
Sig Name, Addr {}
Sig Book { addr: Name -> lone Addr }
```

I'd like to define a predicate for a delete operation, that is to say removing an address where the name is n.

```
pred remove [b, b':Book, n: Name] {
   // What to do?
}
```

Where `b` and `b'` represents the before / after state of the Book.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
pred remove [b, b':Book, n: Name] {
    b'.addr = b.addr - n -> Addr
}
```